# inner join with OR using codeigniter

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

I want to JOIN Table a to Table b OR table c

i have database

```
table a
id
email

table b
id
name
admin

table c
id
name
user
//ilustration
table b.id = 01-admin
table c.id = 01-user
```

if table a.id = 01-user ,i can get data from table c
and data will be looping ON table a

i try example

```
$this->db->select('*');
$this->db->from('a');
$this->db->join('b', 'a.id = b.id');
//OR

$this->db->join('c', 'a.id = c.id');
$query = $this->db->get();
return $query;
```

please help me,
how to write code to JOIN with the conditions OR

Comment: Ok, so what's the condition that decides which join to use?

Comment: yes how her writing code for a review join WITH OR Condition

Comment: Updated my answer check it

Comment: But what is the condition? Like `if(some_logical_test) { join('b') } else { join('c) }`?

Answer (score 0):

Probably use left outer join:

```
$this->db->select('*');
$this->db->from('a');
$this->db->join('b', 'a.id = b.id', 'LEFT OUTER');
$this->db->join('c', 'a.id = c.id' 'LEFT OUTER');
$query = $this->db->get();
return $query;
```

You'd only get things from B or C if it matches.